# Restrict access to service for users after x number of requests

Tags: python, http, flask, rate-limiting

Using Flask, is it possible to make python module that listens requests coming to server by users and count requests. After some time if any of users make, for example, 300 000 requests I want to restrict access to service they are using.

Regarding services.
Our costumers use standard *OGC (WMS, WFS)* services to get access to our spatial data. They access data via URL we provide them when we make service. One service runs on one port. We have multiple services running on multiple ports on one server.

When get request in sent from client to server I want to request first come to flask app and check for number of requests that user made. If number of requests is less than specified number the app should pass request on but if number of request is more than specified number the app should restrict access to data for that user.

I am willing to hear about other technologies that would make this idea work, but python is preferable.

Comment: Please tell us which framework are you gonna use for the server implementation. Anyway, with Flask this question might be of your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949507/why-do-flask-rate-limiting-solutions-use-redis

Comment: I was considering Flask framework.

Answer (score 1):

In flask there is an extension called flask limiter. This extension allows you to limit the amount of request on a particular route. Each route can have different request limits or be exempt to have no limits. It limits user by keeping track of their IP address.

See this documentation: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

example code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(
    app,
    key_func=get_remote_address, # get users IP address.
    default_limits=["300000 per month"], # default limit to 300K request per month
)

@app.route("/spatial-data")
@limiter.limit("300000 per month")
def slow():
    return "720"

app.run()
```

Comment: I would definitely consider this idea, but I am looking for a way that would restrict already made services. For example I have service running on url http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS (this is just an example I found online but services are the same except ours require authentication) and I want to restrict access if a user make more than defined number of requests.

Comment: I also don't want to restrict access per IP since one service can be used by more than one computers.